# Подготовка к коммиту с помощью git add -p "e"(ручное редактирование чанка)

Tags: git

Мы запускаем скрипт который заменяет двойные кавычки на одинарные. Как только скрипт отрабатывает, получается так (выдержка из git diff):

```
 @@ -1,13 +1,13 @@
  module Persey
    module Generators
     class InstallGenerator < ::Rails::Generators::Base
-      source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)
+      source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

  def create_configuration
-        copy_file("config.rb", "config/config.rb")
-        inject_into_file 'config/application.rb', before: "module #{Rails.application.class.parent_name}" do
+        copy_file('config.rb', 'config/config.rb')
+        inject_into_file 'config/application.rb', before: 'module #{Rails.application.class.parent_name}' do
       <<-'RUBY'
-require "persey"
+require 'persey'
require File.expand_path('../config', __FILE__)

         RUBY
```

Необходимо вручную отредактировать чанк,  чтобы git diff выдавал следующее:

```
  @@ -5,7 +5,7 @@ module Persey
   def create_configuration
     copy_file('config.rb', 'config/config.rb')
-        inject_into_file 'config/application.rb', before: "module #{Rails.application.class.parent_name}" do
+        inject_into_file 'config/application.rb', before: 'module #{Rails.application.class.parent_name}' do
       <<-'RUBY'
require 'persey'
require File.expand_path('../config', __FILE__)
```

не пойму как правильно редактировать чанк чтобы получить правильный вывод diff'a. Когда вызываю git add -p, нахожу нужный чанк и начинаю его редактировать - мне гит выдаёт либо ошибку патча, либо вывод diff'a не соответствует требуемому

Comment: я не совсем разобрался в этой теме. на сайте, где давалось задание, по этому поводу сказано: в репозитории исходная строка в файле lib/generators/persey/install/install_generator.rb выглядит так:
       copy_file("config.rb", "config/config.rb")
После того, как выполнили скрипт, получается так... (см. первый фрагмент кода в вопросе) ...Если мы добавим изменения
-        copy_file("config.rb", "config/config.rb")
+        copy_file('config.rb', 'config/config.rb')
в индекс, то при вызове команды git diff эти изменения не отобразятся.

Comment: так как git diff отображается разницу между индексом и рабочей диреткорией, а индекс уже на этот момент будет содержать эти изменения. Поэтому в формулировке задания тут ошибки нет. Вам необходимо достичь указанного диффа, добавив все остальное в индекс, но при этом не добавить ошибки автозамены (сделать это можно как минимум 4 способами - 3 из них красивые и предпочтительные, 1 в лоб).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы откатить изменения в режиме `git add -p` при редактировании чанка нужно удалить строки, начинающиеся с "+" и заменить пробелом (" ") знак "-". Т.е. чтобы изменения:

```
-      source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)
+      source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

  def create_configuration
-        copy_file("config.rb", "config/config.rb")
-        inject_into_file 'config/application.rb', before: "module #{Rails.application.class.parent_name}" do
+        copy_file('config.rb', 'config/config.rb')
+        inject_into_file 'config/application.rb', before: 'module #{Rails.application.class.parent_name}' do
       <<-'RUBY'
-require "persey"
+require 'persey'
```

В следующее:

```
-      source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)
+      source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

  def create_configuration
-        copy_file("config.rb", "config/config.rb")
+        copy_file('config.rb', 'config/config.rb')
         inject_into_file 'config/application.rb', before: "module #{Rails.application.class.parent_name}" do
       <<-'RUBY'
-require "persey"
+require 'persey'
```

Обратите внимание, что строка, начинающаяся с "inject_into_file..." с  лидирующим "-" была перемещена, "-" заменен на " " (пробел), а ненужная строка с лидирующим "+" просто удалена.

После этого `git diff` будет выдавать то, что вы описали в вопросе, а остальное будет в индексе (!). Я не понял причины изменения кавычек, поэтому вопрос уже к вам, нужно ли это в индексе?

Если же вам нужно сбросить "почти все", кроме строки с "inject_into_file...", то можно использовать вместо `git add -p` команду `git checkout -p` с похожим логикой.

Вместо `checkout -p` можно добавить в индекс нужное (`git add -p`), `git checkout` все остальное, а потом `git reset HEAD` на нужный файл.
Так, `git diff` выдаст то, что нужно, а в индексе не будет ничего из этого файла.

Answer (score 1):

как я понял, вам надо часть изменений внести в индекс, чтобы «скрыть» их из результатов команды `git diff`.

покажу на немного упрощённом примере (чтоб нагляднее было).

имеется файл с шестью строками, в которые вписаны цифры от `1` до `6`:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

в третью и четвёртую строки внесены изменения (ну, например, добавлен символ `0`):

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/file b/file
index b414108..068af9e 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 1
 2
-3
-4
+30
+40
 5
 6
```

нам надо внести в индекс исправление третьей строки, но не трогать изменение, внесённое в четвёртую строку.

запускаем `git add -p`, переходим к редактированию (введя команду `e`), и видим такую картину:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 1
 2
-3
-4
+30
+40
 5
 6
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
```

в соответствии с подксказкой, нам надо заменить `-` перед цифрой `4` на пробел, и удалить строку `+40`:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 1
 2
-3
 4
+30
 5
 6
```

но это не совсем то, что требуется. ведь получится, что строка, начинающаяся с цифры `3`, встанет **после** строки, начинающейся с `4`. значит, надо «поднять» её выше:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 1
 2
-3
+30
 4
 5
 6
```

вот теперь всё логично — патч «удаляет» строку, содержащую `3`, и «добавляет» (в том же месте) строку, содержащую `30`.

сохраняем и смотрим результат:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/file b/file
index d1735b0..068af9e 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 1
 2
 30
-4
+40
 5
 6
```

тоже всё верно — осталось лишь изменение четвёртой строки. а третья строка — уже в «новом», отредактированном виде.